# Hilbert metric of a sum of cones

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces, convexity, convex-geometry, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose that $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ are pointed closed cones in a finite-dimensional space $V$ whose Hilbert metrics $d_{1},d_{2}$ are known. Is there a way to express the Hilbert metric of $K_{1}+K_{2}$ in terms of $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$?

Comment: Do you mean the Hilbert projective metric?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the Hilbert metric"?

Comment: @suv....rit Sure